# Only user-defined types defined in public modules can be coerced to or from a variant passed to late-bound functions

Tags: arrays, vb6

I have the following code, whereby I have declared an array or records as Member, the Member type consists of 3 entries, forename, surname and distance. I've tried many variations on my 'call' function but I keep getting the same error:

[image: Error]

Here is a shortened format of my 'whole' code, hoping someone can point out whatever silly mistake I'm making here, I can only assume something within the parameter passing or declaration of the record structure?

[image: Code]

Hope you can help with my school project.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages and code. Post it as text instead.

Comment: perhaps what you want is read_in_file(arrayname() as member)

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for posting a screenshot, first time posting here.  I already tried read_in_file(Members() As Member), but get a compile error, type mismatch, just can't figure out why it's wrong ? @Recoder

Comment: This does work on VB 2017 and even Freebasic. Maybe try passing members() in params.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the message says. You're using a private type, and so it can't be coerced to Variant.

You probably want your `Read_In_File` Sub to instead declare the type of the parameter, rather than using the default Variant type.

```
Private Sub Read_In_File(ByRef Members As Member())
```

Though it's very odd to both have a global variable in your class and a parameter of the same name; so I'm not quite sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you exactly how to solve your issue:

"Only user-defined types defined in public modules can be coerced to or from a variant passed to late-bound functions"

Add a Module to your project called MUserDefinedTypes or modUserDefinedTypes (or whatever naming convention you use) and declare your public user-defined type there.

I also agree with Peter in that you have some funny naming conventions in you code.  Do not name your variables the same as you modules, classes, forms, or types.  It will only get you into trouble.  I suggest a simple prefix approach.

Comment: *"Add a Module to your project called MUserDefinedTypes or modUserDefinedTypes (or whatever naming convention you use) and declare your public user-defined type there.*" That doesn't work (at least in VBA, I don't have VB6 any more), yields the same error. The error message says "public *object* module", which (apparently) means that you need to use a custom class instead of a UDT, if you want to store it in a variant.

Comment: OP question was tagged with vb6, not vba. Cannot comment on vba, sorry.