# Variant holding 2 pointers

Tags: vba

Behind the scene a [Variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) is a structure ([tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)) and can be used to represent any other data type in VBA/VB6 and a couple of special values.

The layout is:

- the first 2 bytes (Integer size) hold the VARTYPE
- bytes 3 to 8 are reserved and mainly not used - Decimal uses them though
- the following bytes can hold:

  - a value e.g. a Double
  - a flag, if VARTYPE is `vbError`
  - a pointer - 4 bytes on x32 and 8 bytes on x64
  - two pointers, hence a `Variant` is 24 bytes on x64. I've seen this mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/10666v1/comment/j3ihipo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) by @sancarn or [here](https://microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop.narkive.com/Zb4ttYYP/variant-size-in-win32-and-win64#post6)

---

I am interested in the last bytes of a Variant for some testing. **When is a Variant holding 2 pointers?**

I want to be able to replicate such an example in VBA. For example, is there any method that I can call from VBA that returns a Variant holding two pointers? I don't care if that method is a Win API definition or a dll/library reference.

Thank you!

Comment: @gserg Apologies for tagging you here, but you might know this from your vast experience. Thanks!

Comment: That's not how it works. You can't just @tag random people, they won't get it. It only works if the person has already participated in the question, e.g. left a comment. I saw this question just now and by complete accident.

Comment: I happen to have no experience in this, but a cursory glance through the documentation suggests it's for passing user-defined types in a Variant. Which requires declaring them in a public module, which you cannot even do in Excel because you will get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54391953/11683). Find/make a properly registered COM library that declares a struct (rather than a class), reference it from VBA and put that struct in a Variant. There are a couple of structs in the standard stdole library, but they cannot be directly used from VBA.

Comment: @GSerg Apologies, I did not know the tagging rule. Many thanks for the info and for reponding. Is it then safe to assume that the 2 pointers can only happen under a ```vbUserDefinedType``` Variant? Is there any way this can happen under a ```vbDataObject``` Variant?

Comment: @GSerg If you post your comment as an answer I will award you the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot do that I'm afraid. It was musings on my side, I'm not even sure it's correct.